# Storing sensitive data with Drupal

Tags: drupal, encryption, sensitive-data

I need to **use sensitive data with Drupal** for a custom module to use. If I simply **set them through the GUI**, they will be **stored unencrypted in the database.** Anyone having access to it will have access to my sensitive data.

I can see two solutions for the moment:

1. Find a way to securely store those credentials into the database;
2. Put those sensitive data into a credentials_inc.php file, include it in settings.php to set variables my custom module could use and make sure that nobody else can read the file.

Which solution is best according to you? What do you recommend? Is there any other best option?

Best regards.

Comment: What kind of sensitive data and do you need to read it back the the screen at some point?

Comment: Credentials to access external web services. And no, we don't need to display them. We just need them for a custom module to use the external web service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start off by using [SecurePages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module, to make sure the data entered somewhere along the way is not snooped.

Then to encrypt the information try using php's [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) with a short example of how to [encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php).

Once the information is secured, you should have no problem storing the data in drupal's db structure. Also, an important note, you might check out [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) instead of trying to append something in settings.php. That is in general a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Lots of information here;). Maybe the encryption module does this all for me directly... I will have to check by myself.

Comment: Its quite possible. It just depends on how much control you want, and how much coding you want to do. If the encryption module does most of it for you, I'd definitely use that, but I would still go with SecurePages as a must.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it is the most complete I believe. Could you please just add a note about the encryption module please?

Comment: Install the Encrypt module, after you do that, goto admin/settings/encrypt, set the encryption type to Basic if you don't have mcrypt phpmod or AES if you do have mcrypt phpmod. Then in your code you only need to use `$encrypted_string = encrypt($string)` then store it in the db (BLOB type) `$decrypted_string = decrypt($encrpyted_string)` to un encrypt it. Check out http://drupal.org/project/encrypt

Comment: Me again. After some additional search and testing, it seems that using the settings.php + include credentials.inc file is not that a bad idea. Actually, if Drupal is compromised and your server is not, your are still safe. If your server is compromised, your are screwed;) I would clearly reconsider which technique to use...

Answer (score 6):

The [Encryption module](http://drupal.org/project/encrypt) provides an API that supports a few different encryption methods, including mcrypt (if you have it enabled).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will see this module.

Answer (score 1):

[The Encryption module](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) is an excellent way to encrypt sensitive data within Drupal.  However, this module does not provide adequate key management (it stores the encryption key within the Drupal database - like storing the keys to your house under your Welcome mat).

Along with Encrypt, you will also need an additional module like [Townsend Security Key Connection](https://www.drupal.org/project/townsec_key?utm_campaign=Securing%20Data%20in%20Drupal%20Stack%20Overflow&utm_source=Securing%20Data%20in%20Drupal%20Stack%20Overflow) which allows you to manage the encryption keys outside of the Drupal database in an encryption key manager (HSM, Cloud, VMware, etc.).  Just remember - if you aren't properly managing your encryption keys, you aren't properly encrypting your data.

Full Disclosure: I work with Townsend Security on the Drupal team.